# Add prefix to debug command in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging a Python script. My configuration looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "debug script.py",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "/path/to/script.py",
  "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

When running the script, I need to prefix it with an executable `aws-access` to give myself access to certain resources on AWS (otherwise I get `Permission Denied` errors):

```
aws-access python script.py
```

How can I add this prefix to the debug command?

Note this is easy to do when executing my code using the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) plugin:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "python": "aws-access $pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
}
```

Comment: can you use the `args` parameter of the launch config. The program to start is `aws-access` and `python` and `script.py` are the arguments

Answer (score 2):

It's a little less smooth than usual, but here's how to do it:

You'll need to have [debugpy](https://pypi.org/project/debugpy/) installed

To initiate the debugging, you'll need a separate function or script that waits for the debugger to attach. I have mine in a separate script that looks like:

```
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(5678)
debugpy.wait_for_client()
    
from foo import bar

bar.run()
```

Where `bar.run()` is what you're trying to debug.

You'll then need to specify a `launch.json` configuration for VSCode - you can create this yourself in the project directory that you're trying to debug under `/.vscode/launch.json` or [create one from within VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

`launch.json` should look something like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach Standard",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

a general debugging flow being:

- within the VSCode terminal, set up your aws credentials either with environment variables, or something like `aws-vault` (which in turn, will set environment variables)
- from the same terminal, run the debug function or script e.g. `python debug_script.py`
- run the function or script with debugging from the VSCode UI(again, I use a script as it makes this part easier and less invasive to your code)

It will respond to UI debug points set in VSCode, and also on `debugpy.breakpoint()` within the code. More importantly, it will use the same terminal session you've set your AWS environment variables in.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to run:

```
saml2aws exec --exec-profile [your-profile-name] --session-duration=3600 -- $SHELL
```

in your VS terminal. Upon subsequent debugging executions, you will stay authenticated (up to the session duration).