# How to prefix file with custom commands when debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797320/add-prefix-to-debug-command-in-vscode) but for PyCharm.

I need to use [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) to access AWS resources in my script, but this seems to be impossible to accomplish in PyCharm debugging mode. It gives ability to enter script path, parameters, environment variables and there is also external tools functionality, but neither of these work.

Here is the format that works in shell:

```
aws-vault exec ${AWS_PROFILE} -- script.py
```

I thought that I've almost arrived at a solution by using external tools and setting the program to "aws-vault" and its arguments to "exec your-profile -- $FilePath$", but it wants to run the script in $FilePath$, finish and only after completion run the debugged script in PyCharm (which is the same one as the one inserted by $FilePath$).

How it would work for my case is by running needed script in debug mode in conjunction with external tool, so the script would go into arguments of the external tool and run as one command.

There are ways to deal with this by launching PyCharm from command line with aws-vault as a prefix or editing its .desktop file and writing the prefix directly into the Exec field, but the app needs to be restarted when AWS profile has to be changed.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by installing the envfile plugin in PyCharm. This plugin can read in a .env file when starting a process. Basically I did the following:

1. Create a script that generates a .env file, `envfile.env` and name the script  `generate.sh`
2. This `generate.sh` script is a shell script that basically does: `aws-vault exec $AWS_PROFILE -- env | grep AWS_ > envfile.env`, so all the aws creds are in the `envfile.env`. Possibly add other environment variables if you need so.
3. Execute command above at least once.
4. Install the envfile plugin in pycharm.
5. In the Run configuration, a new tab appears with 'EnvFile'. In this tab, enable the EnvFile. Add the generated `envfile.env` (see previous).
6. Do Tool / External Tools and create an external tool for the `generate.sh`. This way you can execute the script from PyCharm.
7. Again in the Run configuration add a Before Launch that executes the External Tool `generate.sh`.

Warning, the temporary aws-creds are in the plaintext `envfile.env`.